# jfrog artifactory "invalid character '"' after object key:value pair"

Tags: repository, artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

So I have this spec file in artifactory to remove folders (with artifacts inside)  older than 3 months in more than one repository (3 in this example).

```
{
    "files": [{
        "aql": {
            "items.find": {
                "$or": [{
                    "$and": [{
                        "repo": "repo1",
                        "path": "com/domain/repo1",
                        "created": {
                            "$before": "3mo"
                        }
                        "type": "folder",
                        "name": {"$match":"20*"}
                    }],
                    "$and": [{
                        "repo": "repo2",
                        "path": "com/domain/repo2",
                        "created": {
                            "$before": "3mo"
                        }
                        "type": "folder",
                        "name": {"$match":"20*"}
                    }],
                    "$and": [{
                        "repo": "repo3",
                        "path": "com/domain/repo3",
                        "created": {
                            "$before": "3mo"
                        }
                        "type": "folder",
                        "name": {"$match":"20*"}                    
                    }]
                }]
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

But I´m getting: ***[Error] invalid character '"' after object key:value pair***

How can I tell what is the (***"***) that is causing the error? is not quite descriptive the output like in some other languajes that tells you the line number at least.

On the other hand, if I use following spec for a single repository, it works like a charm.
thank you!

```
{
"files": [{
    "aql": {
        "items.find": {
            "repo": "repo5",
            "path": "com/domain/repo5",
            "created": {
                 "$before": "3mo"
            },
            "type":"folder",
            "name": {"$match":"20*"}
        }
    }
}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma after all of the "created" key/value pairs:

```
"created": {
   "$before": "3mo"
} <-- missing a comma here
"type": "folder",
```

Please notice that your working example has the comma in the right place.